# @PUT with OpenNTF XPages Jakarta EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, xpages, lotus-domino, hcl-notes

I am playing around with the OpenNTF Project "XPages Jakarta EE Support".

I'm trying to setup a REST API for CRUD operations on a Person object.
I managed to create GET and POST requests, but on a PUT request, I get an error in PostMan.

My code to update a request using POST is like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/update/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response update(@PathParam("id") String id, Person p) {
   //TODO save person object
   return Response.ok().type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(p).build();
}
```

This works fine, but when I change the @POST in @PUT, I get a 405 Method Not Allowed:

Unable to Process Request

Http Status Code: 405

Reason: Request method is not allowed by the server

Is @PUT supported in the OpenNTF project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PUT and DELETE are not enabled by default. Open/create an "Internet Site" document in your Domino Directory and enable PUT (and DELETE).

[image]